# Helping understand supremum of non-compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Hi i have a huge problem with finding sup/inf of function when set is not compact. I would be more than glad if anyone could show me how to deal with that kind of tasks.

For instance I have $$f(x,y)=\frac{x\ln{(1+y)}}{2x^2+y^2}$$ on the domain $A=\{(x,y):0<x\le y\le 1\}$ obviously not compact.

I find in this one bounding so we have :$$f(x,y)\le\frac{xy}{2x^2+y^2}\le\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$ And we have $$f(x, \sqrt{2}x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$ So it is my supremum. Bu there are many examples when i don't know how to find boundary, could you show me how to calculate without finding them? I think we can also set one of variables as const and find 1 variable function limit but in this : 
$f(x,y)=x(y-x-1)e^{-y}$ and $A=\{(x,y):0\le x\le y\}$ i couldn't move it even a little no matter which method i choose. Thanks in advance

Comment: In general there is no systematic way. One technique for differentiable functions that often succeeds is to cut out a compact part and find the max/min of that part, which must be at a stationary point or on the boundary (which you try to choose to be something nice and simple), and then you deal with the remainder separately. Usually you choose your boundary to be parametrized by some $ε$ so that the remainder gets smaller and smaller as $ε \to 0$.

Comment: Use `\ln` to get "$\ln$". And your title says "complex" not "compact".

Comment: Corrected, so for second $f'_{x}=e^{-y}(y-2x-1)$ and $f'_{y}=xe^{-y}(x-y+2)$ and my critical points are $(0,1)$ and $(1,3)$ so i assume that for $f(1,3)=e^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ we can have sup but i don't know how to show it. Could you make an example of it and i will try with similar basing on yours? With definitions only i don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, $f(x,y) \le y(y-1)e^{-y} \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$ over the domain of $f$. Since $f$ is not positive on the boundary of the triangular region bounded by $(0,0),(0,m),(m,m)$, you can then conclude that if one of your stationary points has positive value then it is the maximum. The reason is that you can choose some $m$ such that $y(y-1)e^{-y} < f(1,3)$ for any $y > m$, and hence the maximum of the triangular region is the global maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough to say that $lim_{x,y\rightarrow infinity}f(x,y)=0$ and then i say that i can think only about $A=\{(x,y):0\le x\le y\le M\}$ for M big enough to my critical points to belong to A?

Comment: Not quite. As in my answer, you have to find not only the stationary points but also check the value on the boundary of the triangle. Also, you can't consider $x \to \infty$ since outside the triangle $x$ may be small.